# Auto purge, cloudflare and php?

Tags: php, image, caching, cloudflare

my web have a setting page where user can change her image profile, the problem is. I have the dns on cloudflare so if the user change the image I need purge on cloudflare to can see changes, i possible add a code on php for do a auto purge?

Comment: Cloudflare or not its a bog standard caching issue, change the last modified time of the file, or change the url to it. you could use [cloudflares api](https://api.cloudflare.com/#zone-purge-files-by-url) also but if its cached in the browser to it would still require a Shft-F5 anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about saving a timestamp or any kind of identification in your database next to the image url each time your user changes the image?

You would then display it similar to the following:

```
<img src="https://www.yourwebsite.com/images/<?= $image->id ?>?timestamp=<?= $image->updated_at ?>">
```

CloudFlare should treat this as a different file after updating. If it doesn't, you can [set up a page rule that matches your image url and customize the caching](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168306-Is-there-a-tutorial-for-Page-Rules-#cache).